# From Boxplot to Barplot in ggplot possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, errorbar, tukey

I have to do a ggplot **barplot** with **errorbars**, **Tukey sig. letters** for plants grown with different fertilizer concentraitions.
The data should be grouped after the dif. concentrations and the sig. letters should be added automaticaly.

I have already a code for the same problem but for Boxplot - which is working nicely. I tried several tutorials with barplots but I always get the problem; stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic.

So I thought, is it possible to get my boxplot code to a barplot code? I tried but I couldnt do it :) And if not - how do I automatically add tukeyHSD Test result sig. letters to a ggplot barplot?

This is my Code for the boxplot with the tukey letters:

```
    value_max = Dünger, group_by(Duenger.g), summarize(max_value = max(Höhe.cm)) 

hsd=HSD.test(aov(Höhe.cm~Duenger.g, data=Dünger), 

trt = "Duenger.g", group = T) sig.letters <- hsd$groups[order(row.names(hsd$groups)), ]



J <- ggplot(Dünger, aes(x = Duenger.g, y = Höhe.cm))+ geom_boxplot(aes(fill= Duenger.g))+ scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("0.5g", '1g', "2g", "3g", "4g"))+ geom_text(data = value_max, aes(x=Duenger.g, y = 0.1 + max_value, label = sig.letters$groups), vjust=0)+ stat_boxplot(geom = 'errorbar', width = 0.1)+ ggtitle("Auswirkung von Dünger auf die Höhe von Pflanzen") + xlab("Dünger in g") + ylab("Höhe in cm"); J
```

**This is how it looks:**

[boxplot with tukey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufUTB.jpg)

**Data from dput:**

```
structure(list(Duenger.g = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4), plant = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 
21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 31, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 
41, 42, 43, 44, 48, 49, 50, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 61, 62, 64, 
65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 79, 80, 81, 83, 85, 86, 
88, 89, 91, 93, 99, 100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 110, 
111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 120, 122, 123, 125, 126, 
127, 128, 130, 131, 132, 134, 136, 138, 139, 140, 141, 143, 144, 
145, 146, 147, 149), height.cm = c(5.7, 2.8, 5.5, 8, 3.5, 2.5, 
4, 6, 10, 4.5, 7, 8.3, 11, 7, 8, 2.5, 7.4, 3, 14.5, 7, 12, 7.5, 
30.5, 27, 6.5, 19, 10.4, 12.7, 27.3, 11, 11, 10.5, 10.5, 13, 
53, 12.5, 12, 6, 12, 35, 8, 16, 56, 63, 69, 62, 98, 65, 77, 32, 
85, 75, 33.7, 75, 55, 38.8, 39, 46, 35, 59, 44, 31.5, 49, 34, 
52, 37, 43, 38, 28, 14, 28, 19, 20, 23, 17.5, 32, 16, 17, 24.7, 
34, 50, 12, 14, 21, 33, 39.3, 41, 29, 35, 48, 40, 65, 35, 10, 
26, 34, 41, 32, 38, 23.5, 22.2, 20.5, 29, 34, 45)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -105L))
```

Thank you
mirai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bar chart and a boxplot are two different things. By default `geom_boxplot` computes the boxplot stats by default (`stat="boxplot"`). In contrast when you use `geom_bar` it will by default count the number of observations (`stat="count"`) which are then mapped on  `y`. That's the reason why you get an error. Hence, simply replacing `geom_boxplot` by `geom_bar` will not give your your desired result. Instead you could use e.g. `stat_summary` to create your bar chart with errorbars. Additionally I created a summary dataset to add the labels on the top of the error bars.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(agricolae)

Dünger <- Dünger |>
  rename("Höhe.cm" = height.cm) |>
  mutate(Duenger.g = factor(Duenger.g))

hsd <- HSD.test(aov(Höhe.cm ~ Duenger.g, data = Dünger), trt = "Duenger.g", group = T)
sig.letters <- hsd$groups %>% mutate(Duenger.g = row.names(.))

duenger_sum <- Dünger |>
  group_by(Duenger.g) |>
  summarize(mean_se(Höhe.cm)) |>
  left_join(sig.letters, by = "Duenger.g")

ggplot(Dünger, aes(x = Duenger.g, y = Höhe.cm, fill = Duenger.g)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = "mean") +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", width = .1) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("0.5g", "1g", "2g", "3g", "4g")) +
  geom_text(data = duenger_sum, aes(y = ymax, label = groups), vjust = 0, nudge_y = 1) +
  labs(
    title = "Auswirkung von Dünger auf die Höhe von Pflanzen",
    x = "Dünger in g", y = "Höhe in cm"
  )
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
```

[image]

But as the summary dataset now already contains the mean and the values for the error bars a second option would be to do:

```r
ggplot(duenger_sum, aes(x = Duenger.g, y = y, fill = Duenger.g)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), width = .1) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("0.5g", "1g", "2g", "3g", "4g")) +
  geom_text(aes(y = ymax, label = groups), vjust = 0, nudge_y = 1) +
  labs(
    title = "Auswirkung von Dünger auf die Höhe von Pflanzen",
    x = "Dünger in g", y = "Höhe in cm"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - but the sig. letters from the TukeyHSD test isnt in there :)

Comment: Would have added them if you had provided [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data to run your code. (;

Comment: thank you for your reply. I added a little bit of my data with dput and a picture of the how the plot should look in the end but with bars instead of boxplot. I am sitting on this problem for two days now :(

Comment: Hi Mirai. I just edited my answer based on your data.

Comment: Vielen Dank! Das ist perfekt :)